# Couldn't start Android Emulator 5.0

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android Studio 3.3

I create Android Emulator 5.0
Here settings:

[image]

[image]

But when I try to start my app on emulator I get error:

[image]

When press OK in logcat show error message and my app is not install on emulator.

```
05/11 13:55:10: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk D:\dev\myproject\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\tm-debug_0.0.8.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.myproject.android.debug
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

P.S. In Android emulator 9.0 my app success install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because it's not properly installed which is why it shows error even in uninstalling.

I'd suggest you to take backups of your projects and settings and then reinstall the studio from scratch

Comment: After reinstall Android Studio, now success start my app on Android Emulator 5.0